# How to find conditional joint CDF, given an event and a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Random variables X and Y have the joint PDF:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} xy\over4000 & , 1\leq x\leq 3; 40\leq y\leq 60\\ 0 & , \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
For random variable $W = XY$, we define the event $B={W > 80}$. I want to find the conditional joint PDF $f_{X,Y|B}(x,y)$.
I'm having trouble when I'm given functions of random variables, because I'm not sure how to take the cases for W and find the probability of B. I know that the formula is:
$$f_{X,Y|B}(x,y)=\begin{cases} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\over P[B] & , x,y from B\\ 0 & , \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
But I don't know how to find $P[B]$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know how to find P[B]. Any ideas?

Yes, as usual, by definition

$$\mathbb{P}[XY>80]=\mathbb{P}\left[Y>\frac{80}{X}\right]$$

thus all you have to do is to integrate $f(x,y)$ in the specified region...

that is the purple area here below

[image]

Comment: This would be $\mathop{\int_1^3\int_{80\over x}^{60}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,dx \,dy$?

Comment: @Andrei0408: the easiest way is the following

$$\int_{40}^{60}\left[ \int_{80/y}^3 f(x,y)dx \right]dy$$

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you for the graph, it helps a lot!!